# Allow access to a route/url from specific ip address

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

As the title said, how to use htaccess to allow certain IP to access controller `/admin` in Codeigniter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the application level but if you really want it in the`.htaccess` then:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

#url to apply rule to
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /admin$

#ip to allow access
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^111\.222\.333\.444$

#send to root if ip is not allowed
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It's working but how you put this restriction for certain controller? I tried ErrorDocument 403 /admin , but it also effect the front-page also

Comment: @oitoit I am updating my answer :)

Comment: @oitoit how about this one?

Comment: the ip filtering. I put IP like example of yours (111\.222\.333\.444) to see if I can still access. And yes, I can still access the admin page

Comment: hey, the last one is working now! if I want to put multiple IP, should I just repeat the line (RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^111\.222\.333\.444$) ? Thank you so much majimboo!!

Comment: @oitoit yes, just keep repeating that line.

Answer (score 1):

simply in your controller write-

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != $your_ip_address)) {
   exit();
}
```

Comment: how about using htaccess to do it?

Comment: yes, you can also use .htacces for this using allow deny but it will be difficult to provide the logic that it has to be implemented on certain controllers only,

Comment: and thank you also sunny, i will use this php approach as the alternative :)

Comment: my pleasure! m glad you found the answer!